# The expected value of the second pivot in gauss jordan eliminaton

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, expected-value

Say I have a matrix

```
x1 x2
x3 x4
```

With x1, x2, x3 and x4 randomly and uniformly drawn from the interval [0,1]

After I do gauss-jordan elimination, what is the expected value of the absolute value of the second pivot (the one on the x4 position)?

So far I seem to be getting a surprinsing answer: infinity

For the second pivot can be calculated as $x4-(x3/x1)*x2$. Therefore, the sought expected value is $E(x4-(x3/x1)*x2) = E(x4)-E(x2)*E(x3)*E(1/x1) = 0.5-0.5*0.5*E(1/x1)$.

But $E(1/x1)=\infty$ (see [Expectation of 1/x, x uniform from 0 to 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031259/expectation-of-1-x-x-uniform-from-0-to-1)).

Is there an error somewhere in my thinking? Where can I read a bit more about this?

Comment: Is the answer just $1$? The columns will be linearly independent with probability equal to $1$.

Comment: I dont think so. Is my calculation of the second pivot wrong? I am following the steps of gauss-jordan elimination. Also, the fact that the columns are (probably)  linearly independent does not seem to imply anything about the value of the second pivot (except that the lines are also probably LI and then the second pivot is probably not zero)

Answer (score 1):

Your computation appears to be correct to me. It's also supported by the following little bit of matlab code:

```
function gjtest(n)
mats = rand(4, n);

cells = zeros(n, 1);
for i = 1:n
    s = reshape(mats(:,i), 2, 2);
    s(2,:) = s(2,1)/s(1,1) * s(2,:);
    cells(i) = s(2,2);
end
mean(cells)
clf;
plot(cells); 
figure(gcf);
```

which produces, as mean values:

```
n       mean
1000     2.17...
10000    2.14...
100000   2.94...
1000000  3.100...
10000000 4.441...
```

which is not growing very fast, I admit, but certainly suggests that the mean is not $1$.

So you have a random variable with a very high mean, but the odd characteristic that its "population mean" tends to be a great deal smaller. I think this indicates lots of "skew" in the data (I apologize if I'm misusing statistics terms...it's been a long time). The plots from running those code fragments certainly suggest a very biased distribution. If you replace "plot" with "histogram" you can see what I mean.

In fact, let me add a little more. The pivot $X$ is (up to small perturbation), roughly $1/x_1$. How is this distributed? Well,

\begin{align}
P(a-u < X < a+u) 
&= P(a-u < \frac{1}{x_1} < a + u)\\
&= P(\frac{1}{a+u} < x_1 < \frac{1}{a - u}\\
&= \frac{1}{a-u} - \frac{1}{a + u}\\
&= \frac{(a+u) - (a-u)}{(a-u)(a+u)}\\
&= \frac{2u}{a^2-u^2}\\
&\approx \frac{2u}{a^2}\\
\end{align}
for small values of $u$. The pdf, gotten by taking a limit of difference quotients, therefore gives 
$$
p(x) = \frac{1}{a^2}
$$
This explains why there are so few large values of $X$ -- the probability falls off quadratically with the target values. But it also explains why the expected value is infinite: if you look at $x p(x)$, whose integral is the mean of $X$, you find you're integrating $\frac{1}{x}$, which gives you a $\log$, and the integral diverges. Then again, it diverges about as slowly as something possibly *can* [I'm speaking informally here!], so it's no surprise that the values I was getting were in the $2$ to $5$ range. :)

Comment: that is very interesting discussion. Thanks!